# xp:viewPanel - Leading and closing empty table row

Tags: xpages

I have the following simple xpage with a xp:viewPanel :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel1" disableTheme="true">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="testView"></xp:dominoView>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="$0" id="viewColumn1">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Col 1" id="viewColumnHeader1"></xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>
</xp:viewPanel>
</xp:view>
```

Although pagers are disabled for header and footer, the generated HTML has always a leading an closing empty row around the view data:

```
<table id="view:_id1:viewPanel1_OUTER_TABLE" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

 <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td colspan="3" style="padding:0px" width="100%" height="100%" valign="top">
     <table id="view:_id1:viewPanel1">
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th scope="col">
             <div><span><span id="view:_id1:viewPanel1:viewColumn1:__internal_header_title_id">Col 1</span></span></div>         
           </th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td>
          <span id="view:_id1:viewPanel1:0:viewColumn1:_internalViewText">&nbsp;</span>         
         </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>

  </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>

</table>
```

What can I do to hide/ delete this empty rows?

I already added an empty theme and used it in the test database, but that did not help:

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="platform:/plugin/com.ibm.designer.domino.stylekits/schema/stylekit.xsd">
</theme>
```

I am using Domino Domino 8.5.3 Upgrade Pack 1

Thx in advance
Daniel

---

Edit 04/24/2012 :

Thanks to Ulrich Krause, his answer gave me the right direction and I ended up in writing my own theme extension.

```
<theme extends="webstandard" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="platform:/plugin/com.ibm.designer.domino.stylekits/schema/stylekit.xsd">

  <!-- ================== View Table with no footer and header ================================ -->
    <!-- View DataTable - copied from webstandard theme and customized  (Notes\xsp\nsf\themes)-->
    <control >
            <name>DataTable.ViewPanelNoHeaderFooter</name>
            <property>
                    <name>headerEndStyle</name>
                    <value>display: none;</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                    <name>headerStartStyle</name>
                    <value>display: none;</value>
            </property>           
            <property>
                    <name>headerStyle</name>
                    <value>display: none;</value>
            </property>


            <property>
                    <name>footerStyle</name>
                    <value>display: none;</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                    <name>footerStartStyle</name>
                    <value>display: none;</value>
            </property>           
            <property>
                    <name>footerEndStyle</name>
                    <value>display: none;</value>
            </property>
    </control>
</theme>
```

With that theme extension i can set the theme id for my xp:viewPanel to "DataTable.ViewPanelNoHeaderFooter" where needed and the header and footer row are hidden.

```
<xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel1" 
    themeId="DataTable.ViewPanelNoHeaderFooter">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="testView"></xp:dominoView>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="$0" id="viewColumn1">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Col 1" id="viewColumnHeader1">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>

</xp:viewPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using a theme for this. It sets the empty .xspDataTableViewPanelHeaderStart etc to display:none. 
Inspect with firebug to find the elements. Would post solution, but only have a smartphone at the moment.

Comment: Thank you, that gave me the right direction to have a look into the themes. I ended up in writing my own control in the theme which I can use via the theme id property of the view panel. I documented this approach in my question above.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  disableTheme="true" as a property of the pager and see if that gets rid of the code.

```
    <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next"
            xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1" disableTheme="true">
        </xp:pager>
```

Comment: Hi, changing the disableTheme property of the pager or the view panel itself didn't change the behavior, the header and footer row were still created